# Can SoapUi publish arbitrary messages onto a JMS Queue?

Tags: automated-tests, jms, soapui

In the past my team has often used SoapUi to create automated tests around our SOAP webservice. Now we would like to create automated tests around our app's JMS communication. Therefore, we need to configure SoapUi to publish to and consume from our JMS queues.

The [SoapUi website](https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages.html) explains how to publish SOAP messages to a JMS queue. But this does not fit my usecase; my app sends arbitrary text messages over JMS without conforming to a SOAP contract.

Is SoapUi able to publish arbitrary text messages to a JMS queue, or must my messages conform to a SOAP contract defined by a wsdl? How would I configure SoapUi to publish these messages without it creating a dummy SOAP interface for the JMS connection to reside in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free version of SoapUi is intended to use test SOAP and REST. As the above link shows, SoapUi can be configured - through its GUI - to send messages over JMS *only* when these messages conform to a SOAP contract. However, SoapUi is also able to execute Groovy scripts, and these Groovy scripts can publish arbitrary messages to JMS. With the help of my team, I wrote a Groovy script which imports a Java library and uses this to publish arbitrary JMS messages.